# Docker loses network connectivity after starting

Tags: linux, docker

I have a weird issue in Linux, running under SLES12 over VMWare. After I start docker by issuing service docker start I lose network connectivity to the Linux machine from putty... In order to get back to it I have to ssh to it from another Linux machine. So it seems like its moving my interfaces out of order

Before starting docker

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:B6:33:30
          inet addr:10.100.0.101  Bcast:10.100.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:feb6:3330/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163546 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70909 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18524059 (17.6 Mb)  TX bytes:15505464 (14.7 Mb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1425313 (1.3 Mb)  TX bytes:1425313 (1.3 Mb)
```

and `ifconfig` after

```
$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:D6:7A:25:1C
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:d6ff:fe7a:251c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:26040 (25.4 Kb)  TX bytes:1394 (1.3 Kb)

docker_gw Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:01:39:74:46
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:1ff:fe39:7446/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:5206 (5.0 Kb)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:B6:33:30
          inet addr:10.100.0.101  Bcast:10.100.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:feb6:3330/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:164222 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:71533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18582001 (17.7 Mb)  TX bytes:15580880 (14.8 Mb)
```

Comment: Before and after starting swarm:

Comment: docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
b62e8ad6a082        bridge              bridge              local
500f74f46b14        host                host                local
e419dd895f4a        none                null                local

Comment: after docker swarm init
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
b62e8ad6a082        bridge              bridge              local
e5f5c2f138db        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
500f74f46b14        host                host                local
omk1mi736ttj        ingress             overlay             swarm
e419dd895f4a        none                null                local

Answer (score 0):

that's happens because of wrong route ip or conflict mac addresses

you can see with #ip a   and #ip r command whats happen

if you want more help send your ip r export here

you can change default gateway to fix your network with 
/sbin/route add default gw [Youtip]